# How to maximize data transfer speed over USB (configured as virtual com port)

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port, usb, stm32

I have troubles to get my streaming over OTG-USB-FS configured as VCP. In my disposition I have nucleo-h743zi board that seems to doing a good job at sending me data, but on PC side I have a problem to receive that data.

```
for(;;) {

#define number_of_ccr 1024
unsigned int lpBuffer[number_of_ccr] = {0};
unsigned long nNumberOfBytesToRead = number_of_ccr*4;
unsigned long lpNumberOfBytesRead;


QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCounter);  
ReadFile(
  hSerial,
  lpBuffer,
  nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  &lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  NULL
  );

if(!strcmp(lpBuffer, "end\r\n")) {
  CloseHandle(FileHandle);
  fprintf(stderr, "end flag was received\n");
  break;
}
else if(lpNumberOfBytesRead > 0) {
  // NOTE(): succeed
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCounter);
  time = Win32GetSecondsElapsed(startCounter, endCounter);

  char *copyString = "copy";
  WriteFile(hSerial, copyString , strlen(copyString), &bytes_written, NULL);
  DWORD BytesWritten;
  // write data to file
  WriteFile(FileHandle, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, &BytesWritten, 0);
}

}
```

QPC shows that speed was 0.00733297970 - it's one time for one successful data block transfer (1024*4 bytes).

this is the Listener code, I bet that this is not how it should be done, so I here to seek advices. I was hopping that maybe full streaming without control sequences ("copy") will be possible, but in that case I can't receive adjacent data (within one transfer block it's OKAY, but two consecutive received blocks aren't adjacent.

Example:
block_1: 1 2 3 4 5 6
block_2: 13 14 15 16 17 18

Is there any way to speed up my receiving?
(I was trying O2 key without any success)

Comment: you do not check return values, you do not have any error handling. With this code you cant get any conclusions. Try a bit harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure buffer on PC side that will be 2 or 3 times the buffer you are transfer from your board, and use something like double buffer scheme for transferring the data. You transfer the first buffer while filing the second, then alternate.
Good thing to do is to activate caches, and place the buffers in fast memory for stm32h7 (it's 1 domain RAM).

But if your interface do not match the speed you needed, there will be no tricks to do this. Except maybe one, if your controller is fast enough -> you can implement and use lossless data compression on that data of yours and transfer compressed files. If you transmit low entropy data, this could give you a solid boost in speed.

Comment: and the problem with data contingency could thrive from heavily loaded interrupt routines using.

Comment: I recommend for you to try and reconsider your program design and do not use interrupts heavily, especially when you need to transfer some data over bottleneck interface

Comment: Wow, thank you! I actually forgot about this question)